# CUnit (undefined reference)

Tags: c, stack, cunit

I need to write a program using C and CUnit to test some simple stack functions and using "Makefile" but when I try to compile it, I always get the same errors. The terminal on ubuntu show this when I write the "make" command:

```
gcc -o Pilhaa_teste.o Pilhaa_teste.c -lcunit
/tmp/ccLqNqAx.o: In function `main':
Pilhaa_teste.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `clean_suite1'
Pilhaa_teste.c:(.text+0x26): undefined reference to `init_suite1'
Pilhaa_teste.c:(.text+0x50): undefined reference to `testaTOP'
```

The .h that I wrote is:

```
typedef struct No {
    struct No *prox;
    int info;
}no;

typedef struct pilha {
    no *topo;
}Pilha;

int init_suite1(void);

int clean_suite1(void);

void testaTOP(void);

/*create empty stack*/
Pilha *cria_pilha(void);

/*add one element to the stack*/
void push (Pilha *p, int valor);

/*free first element of stack*/
void pop (Pilha *p);

/*print and find first element*/
int top (Pilha *p);

/*free stack*/
void libera(Pilha *p);

/*print stack*/
void imprime(Pilha *p);
```

the .c with the main code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "pilha.h"
    #include "CUnit/Basic.h"


int main(){
    CU_pSuite pSuite = NULL; 

    if (CUE_SUCCESS != CU_initialize_registry())
      return CU_get_error();

    pSuite = CU_add_suite("Suite_1", init_suite1, clean_suite1);
        if(NULL == pSuite){
        CU_cleanup_registry();
        return CU_get_error();
    }

    if(NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite, "test of top()", testaTOP)){
        CU_cleanup_registry();
        return CU_get_error();
    }


    CU_basic_set_mode(CU_BRM_VERBOSE);
    CU_basic_run_tests();
    CU_cleanup_registry();
    return CU_get_error();
}
```

and the clean_suite1, init_suite1 and testaTOP functions:

```
    static Pilha *p = NULL;

    int init_suite1(void){
        push(p, 6);
        if(p!=NULL)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    int clean_suite1(void){
        pop(p);
        if (p == NULL)
            return 0;
        else
            return 1;
    }

    void testaTOP(void){
        Pilha *p = NULL;
         push (p, 6);
        if (p != NULL){
            CU_ASSERT(top(p) == 6);
            push (p, 7);
            if (p != NULL)
                CU_ASSERT(top(p) ==7 );
        }

        no *aux = p->topo->prox;
        free(p);
        free(aux);

    }
```

the basic functions, push, pop and others are written but there are no problems with them. They were previously used in another program of mine.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -o` compiles and links your sources, so either add the .c where functions are implemented or compile separately with `gcc -c`, which doesn't link source files.